# How do you manipulate this in 2D

Tags: vector-calculus, homework

Use Manipulate to create an interactive plot that shows the parametrically-defined curve described by `{x[t], y[t]} = {t Sin[t], t^2/15}` for `{t,0,10}` along with a point of tangency, tangent vector, and tangent line to the curve for any choice of `t` between `0` and `10`.

```
Clear[t, x, y, P, velvector, vel, scalefactor]; 
scalefactor = 0.5; 
P[t_] = {t Sin[t], t^2/15}; 
curveplot = ParametricPlot[P[t], {t,0,10}, PlotStyle -> Thickness[0.01], 
AxesLabel -> {"x", "y","z"}];
vel[t_] = D[P[t], t]; 
velvector[t_] := Vector[vel[t], Tail -> P[t], VectorColor -> Red, ScaleFactor 
-> scalefactor];
Manipulate[Show[curveplot, velvector[t],{t,0,10}, PlotRange -> All]]
```

Something not right here, it failed.

Comment: ...and do you have any code showing your attempt at solving this?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: Most users on this site will not be too interested in just doing a problem for someone, *especially* if it's homework (many of us are educators, so we don't look kindly on people asking us to do their homework). What exactly about this problem is giving you trouble? Is it how to use `Manipulate` (see the documentation)? Is it how to plot a point, line, and vector on top of a graph (construct the objects using math and use `Graphics` to make the pictures, then use `Show`: see the docs)? Is it how to make a parametric plot to begin with (use the docs)? Be specific, and show your work.

Comment: ​Clear[t, x, y, P, velvector, vel, scalefactor];
scalefactor = 0.5;
P[t_] = {t Sin[t], t^2/15};
curveplot = ParametricPlot[P[t], {t,0,10}, PlotStyle -> Thickness[0.01], AxesLabel -> {"x", "y","z"}]
vel[t_] = D[P[t], t];
velvector[t_] := Vector[vel[t], Tail -> P[t], VectorColor -> Red, ScaleFactor -> scalefactor];
From here I have my vector and my curve. How do i plot it in parametrization of using manipulate with the constraint of t?
Manipulate[Show[curveplot, velvector[t],{t,0,3}, PlotRange -> All]]

Comment: Please edit your question to include the code in your comment.

Comment: @user41325.  Thank you for including your code! Now we have something to work with.

Comment: What is Vector? Mma shows no such a function. Didi you define it earlier?

Comment: There are few syntax issues here. Line `Show` contents must be wrapped in `{}` like `Show[{(*your content goes here*)}]`. Also, I don't think you need `Table` wrapped around `valvector[t]` function.

Comment: What are you trying to do with the `Table[]`?

Comment: `curveplot` is not a function of `t`; there is a syntax error in `Table`. I cannot help more since I don't understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: ^ THANK YOU GOT IT :)

Answer (score 1):

I guess what you are looking for is something like this

```
scalefactor = 0.5;

P[t_] = {t Sin[t], t^2/15};

curveplot[t0_] := ParametricPlot[P[t], {t, 0, t0},
                  PlotStyle -> Thickness[0.01], AxesLabel -> {"x", "y"}]

vel[t_] = D[P[t], t];
velvector[t0_] := Graphics[{Red, Arrow[{P[t0], P[t0] + scalefactor vel[t0]}]}]

Manipulate[Show[curveplot[t], velvector[t], PlotRange -> {{0, 2}, {0, 1}},
           AspectRatio -> 1], {t, 1, 10}]
```

[image]